# By changing width task environment is not working properly

Tags: tasks

I am working in `extbook`document class. I prepared my book with setting width size 7 inches by using the command

```
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=7in,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
```

But if I change my width size to 6 inches then task environment is NOT giving required output.

My code is

```
    ...
    \usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=7in,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
    ...

    \NewTasks[counter-format = {\bf tsk[1].},label-width=24pt]{numbering}[\op]

    ...

    \section{Answers}
    \begin{numbering}(5)
    \op (C)
    \op (A)
    \op (C)
    \op (A)
    \op (B)
    \op (D)
    \op (D)
    \op (C)
    \op (A)
    \op (D)
    \op (C)
    \op (A)
    \op (A)
    \op (C)
    \op (B)
    \op (D)
    \op $\pm2$, $\pm\sqrt2$
    \op*(3) $(q-s)^2-rqp-rsp+sp^2+qr^2$
    \op\SetTaskNumber{21} (D)
    \op (B)
    \op (A)
    \op (C)
    \op (C)
    \end{numbering}
...
```

The ouput of this code is perfecly alright but if I change the width size to 6 inches the output is not good. I am sharing both outputs. Please tell me what alterations do I need to do if I want the same as it is in the width of 7 inches.

I use font size 10 pt for 7 inches width and 9 pt for 6 inches width by using the command `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{extbook}`.

[image: width is 7 inches with font size 10 pt]
[image: width is 6 inches with font size 9 pt]

Comment: Could you pease prepare a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get? Which version of the `tasks` package are you using?

Comment: @leandriis I am using TexShop version 3.62. I am not sure how to check the version of `tasks'.

Comment: You'll find it in the .log file.

Comment: @Bernard I found there `tasks 2016/05/04 v0.11a`.

Comment: Good gracious! Present version is  1.1 (3/11/2019). Furthermore the syntax for the labels has changed not so long ago. You definitely should update, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard In order to update task version, I need to update my TexShop, right?

Comment: @prashantsharma That's better... I hope...

Comment: I think if somehow I could reduce the column separtion in tasks, then it would solve my problem. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I updated my TexShop but the task version is still the same.

Comment: Please download the latest version of `TeXshop` else download `MacTeX` and install it (hope you are using MAC system)...

Comment: For the sake of completeness: in an up to date version of `tasks` you simply do `\setcounter{task}{21}`